# Referring to site URL in shortcode argument

Tags: shortcode, site-url

Apologies for the noob question -- have searched extensively, and it's probably a forehead-slapper.

A plugin I'm using offers a shortcode that takes a URL as an argument; I should set that argument to the URL of a particular page on my site. For example:

```
[cool-shortcode arg_needing_URL="URL of site page goes here"]
```

How can I avoid hardcoding the URL? I'm working on localhost for the moment, but I'd like the argument to work no matter where the code is hosted. I could tinker with the PHP for the shortcode to allow a special argument syntax meaning "look up this constant," but that feels like using a chainsaw to open an envelope. Does WP have a syntax for referring to constants from your content?

Comment: mm it's always the same URL or it's the url of the page, or needs to be a setting that can be changed from the admin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the heart of your question: no, WordPress does not have a way of referencing posts by ID/slug/etc. within the post content. In fact, probably the recommended way to do that is with a...shortcode! Even that wouldn't help you in this case, though, since you can't nest shortcodes [without a plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/nested-shortcodes/).

So I'd recommend you use your own shortcode, or plug theirs if it's [a pluggable function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions). Simply replacing their URL argument with a `get_permalink()` that accepts an ID from the shortcode is probably all that's required.

Comment: Well, sounds like it wasn't a forehead-slapper after all. I'm fine with the coding, so I'll dive into shortcode-land. Thanks!